# Adding scripts to build process in Ionic2

Tags: ionic2

I'm trying to add a simple script to my build process that I'm using to update the build version and build date of my app.

I can't seem to work out where to add this in the hooks.

I would normally add this task into gulp or grunt during the build, but since Ionic2 has removed gulp from the process and has it's build scripts in a file that is in the node_modules, I can't edit that in order to keep it constant across all the people working on the project.

I've tried putting the script in the before_build, after_build, after_prepare and several others, but running them before the build command or serve command etc causes my script t run before the entire built in build process or after the entire process not during.

The script ideally would run before the minify and uglify in the current ionic_app_scripts
or even as part of the copy so it could copy the files then change some variables on the copied rather than on the source.

I recall seeing something about overriding the build scripts using the config.xml but I haven't been able to find that resource again.

In Ionic and in Angular2 and angularJS I would usually use either grunt tasks or gulp tasks to achieve this, but the Ionic team has removed gulp from the project currently.

Anyone know a way of doing this?

Comment: Link to a very similar question in the ionic forums, also without an answer. https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/string-replace-during-build/80210